# React App - After Deployment Blank Page on Refresh for all Children pages. Locally all works perfect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, aws-amplify

My React App won't render any of children pages (including `NotFound` page) when refresh is performed.
When using buttons within the app, all pages renders correctly. **This is happening only on hosting environment.** I tried traditional hosting and deploying my app through cPanel and currently at AWS Amplify but the same issue at both of them.
And this is the only error I'm getting in the console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

I tried all advices found over the interned fighting with this for over two days already but nothing works.
**Actually one thing work which is `<HashRouter>`** which inserts the "#" between the domain name and the page name and stores the values in #. With `HashRouter` all works perfectly but this solution is not  advised by the React creators in official docs

This is my App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Welcome from './pages/Welcome';
import HomeUS from './pages/HomeUS';
import HomeGB from './pages/HomeGB';
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Welcome />} />
        <Route path="/us/*" element={<HomeUS />} />
        <Route path="/gb/*" element={<HomeGB />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} /> {/* Add this catch-all route */}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

This is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import "./index.scss"
import App from "./App";
import AOS from "aos"
import 'aos/dist/aos.css';

const root = document.getElementById('root');
const appRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(root);

appRoot.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

AOS.init({
  duration: 1400
});
```

I've tried to remove `</React.StrictMode>` advised by some users but still the same issue.

And here is my package.json settings file:

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "homepage": "./",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2"
  }
}
```

Where I've changed the homepage already to suggested:

```json
"homepage": "./",
"homepage": "/",
"homepage": "https://example.com",
```

But none of them works.

At my server.js I have also all routes redirection to index.html:

```js
// Serve the React app for all routes
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

Has been told by ChatGPT and my hosting support that this is because standard hosting doesn't support Client Side Routing for SPAs but moved to AWS which definitely do but still the same issue.

Comment: There's nothing "nasty" about the `HashRouter`, it serves a unique purpose, just like `BrowserRouter`, `MemoryRouter`, etc. all do. The basic gist is that the server/hosting service needs to serve the root index.html file. Have you checked the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#aws-amplify) for AWS Amplify to see what you may need to configure so the client app code is correctly served so routing/navigation can be handled internally? Can you share how you've configured the server/host?

Comment: to pinpoint the problem more, maybe try to render just a h1 instead of a page. 
My thought is what if it is having issue resolving the relative paths of the page components when its building on the host becuase what ever reason.

i suggest you render a path like this: 
<Route path="/test" element={<h1>test is good<h1/>} />

I think this could help pinpoint the issue more.

(i would also remove the AOS packge when testing to fix this issue. again, this is only to pinpoint the problem better)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I've fixed this!
Thanks for all the hints guys!
I've check all the mentioned points but I ended up adding those below rules to the "Rewrites and redirects" section and all works perfectly now!

[image]

But exactly the same rules added to the standard shared hosting are not working so AWS is handling this much better I guess. And to be honest similar rules was added by Amplify before and they wasn't working, so I've no ide why it does now. I've must done something wrong before.

Once again big thanks for speedy answers! Didn't expected that. Smile is back :)

Happy coding!